# Can this year's free extension-to-pay be filed electronically? IRS Form 1127

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

Does anyone know if [IRS Form 1127](http://www.irs.gov/formspubs/article/0,,id=244947,00.html) can be filed electronically?  I didn't find mention on their site either way so I presume not.  But considering they're pushing to go paperless nowadays like most....

Comment: Just be sure that you understand very clearly that you can request an extension of time to **file** your income tax return, but not an extension of time to **pay the tax due.**  You still have to estimate how much you expect to owe and pay that by the original due date of the tax return (April 15 or soon thereafter depending on weekends, legal holidays in the District of Columbia, etc). When you file your return by mid-October, it might show a refund (which you will get back with interest) or even more tax due (which you will have to pay, together with interest, and possibly, penalties).

Comment: See [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2156829_use-form-1127-extension-time.html), or the link above from the IRS directly.  What you're referring to is the old form IRS Form 4868: extention to _file_ not pay.  This extension to _pay_ appears new. And penalty-free if you qualify.

Comment: Anyway, for several years already I've been able to electronically file not only Form 4868 when needed but also 1040 and 540(CA) taxes themselves, and not the EZ kind--including Schedule D--very convenient. With payment or refund, using software or directly online. It's true that I've always had to pay at least _estimates_ due April if applicable, even if fully filed later.

Comment: But if you read the start of the web page you refer to, it says that the form is for an extension of time to pay an amount that is shown on your tax return as due, or as assessed by the IRS after it examines your return and comes up with a different number. So until you file your return on October 15, the question of asking for an extension to pay seems moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Form 1127 (updated link)](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1127,-Application-for-Extension-of-Time-for-Payment-of-Tax-Due-to-Undue-Hardship) should be filed in paper (with the supporting documents) to the IRS office that has jurisdiction in the area where you live.

From the instructions (see the link above):

> File Form 1127 with the Internal Revenue Service (Attn: Advisory Group
> Manager), for the area where you maintain your legal residence or
> principal place of business. See [Pub. 4235](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4235.pdf), Collection Advisory Group
> Addresses, to find the address for your local advisory group.
>
> However, if the tax due is a gift tax reportable on Form 709, send Form 1127
> to:
>
> Department of the Treasury
>
> Internal Revenue Service Center
>
> Cincinnati, OH 45999